# как разрешить пользователю в домене обновлять программу- не давая ему админа целиком?

Tags: windows, администрирование, установка, домен

Есть приложение, которое часто просит обновляться, причем скачивает установочные пакеты всегда с разным именем в папку темп и оттуда пытается устанавиться. Естественно установка запрещена обычному пользователю. Как дать ему права на установку чисто из это директории или от производителя данной программы. Надоело каждый раз бегать вводить пользователю пароль админа.

Comment: Я предлагаю повысить привилегии через шедулер, т.е.  создать задачу для запуска приложения с повышенными правами. А потом уже просто инициировать [запуск](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html) задачи.

Comment: название инсталляционного пакета всегда разное

Comment: Если я правильно понял, речь идет о программе (исполнимом файле), который сам инициирует запуск обновления. Зачем нам знать, что он запускает?Нужно лишь дать ему (процессу) полномочия админа, а уж что он запустит - дело разработчика.

Comment: @Daemon-5 ну вот, как дать процессу полномочия админа не давая полномочия всему пользователю?

Comment: Я же в первом комментарии дал ссылку! Там по шагам описана процедура.

Comment: @Daemon-5, следую инструкциям в вашей ссылке, но в планировщике возникает ошибка 2147943645,  говорит не хватает доступа. Если задать запуск от моего юзера - запускает

Comment: Да, проверил - не работает указанный метод. Поискал другие способы с использованием встроенных средств - ничего не нашел. Поэтому могу только посоветовать использовать сторонние решения: **[Sudo](https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/5-windows-alternatives-linux-sudo-command/)**. Sudo for windows под Win7 работала без особых ухищрений, насчет поздних версий ничего сказать не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Если софт подписан сертификатом, то посмотреть в сторону SoftwareRestrictionPolicies и создать правило для сертификата.
При этом необходимо учитывать тот момент, что в реестр может не дать писать, ну и NTFS права на папку с программой тоже надо будет подправить, чтобы юзер туда писать смог.

Comment: можно более подробные материалы по настройке данного раздела в АД ?